# How can i import variables to another class?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make a prototype for a game i have to make for school. But it isnt going great. My question is how can i import a variable from one class to another? I want the playerX and Y variable so i can check collision. This is written in Processing (Java).

If there's a better way of checking collision please tell me :) im out of ideas. Thanks in advance!

My code:

Main class

```
Player thePlayer = new Player();
Guard theGuard = new Guard();
SpeedPWRUP speedPowerUp = new SpeedPWRUP();

void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);
  theGuard.init();
  thePlayer.init();
  speedPowerUp.init();
}

void updateGame() {
  theGuard.update();
  thePlayer.update();
  speedPowerUp.update();
}

void drawGame() {
  thePlayer.draw();
  theGuard.draw();
  speedPowerUp.draw();
  fill(color(255, 255, 255));
  text("Score:", 10, 20);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill (0, 0, 0);
  rect(-10, 401, 1100, 100);
  noFill();

  updateGame();
  drawGame();
}
```

Guard class

```
class Guard {
  public float guardX, guardY;
  float guardVX, guardVY;
  int fillColor;
  float guardHeight, guardWidth;

void init() {
   guardHeight = 80;
   guardWidth = 40;
   guardX = 300;
   guardY = 400-guardHeight;
   fillColor = color(255,0,0);
}

void update() {
  if (guardX == (random(width)-100)) 
    guardVX = 3;

  if (guardX == (random(width)+100)) 
    guardVX = -3;

  guardX += guardVX;
  guardY += guardVY;
}

void draw() {
  fill(fillColor);
  rect(guardX, guardY, guardWidth, guardHeight);
  noFill();
}
}
```

Player class

```
class Player {
  public float playerX, playerY;
  float vx, vy;
  int fillColor;
  float playerHeight, playerWidth;
  float jumpTime;
  float jumpHeight;
  boolean isJumping;

void init() {
  playerHeight = 80;
  playerWidth = 40;
  fillColor = color(0, 0, 0);
  jumpTime = 200;
  jumpHeight = 100;
  isJumping = false;

  playerX = 100;
  playerY = 400-playerHeight;

  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
}

void update() {

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
      vx = -2;
    }
  } else {
    vx = 0;
  }

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
      vx = 2;
    }
  } else {
    vx = 0;
  }

  if (keyPressed) {
    if ((key == 'w' || key == 'W') && ( playerY > 400 - jumpHeight)) {
      isJumping = true;
    }
  } else {
    isJumping = false;
  }

  if (playerY < 400 - jumpHeight) {
  }

  if (keyPressed) {
    if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
      playerHeight = 40;
    }
  } else {
    playerHeight = 80;
  }

  if(isJumping == true) {
    vy = -15;
  } else {
    vy = 0;
  }

  if (playerY < (400-playerHeight)) {
  vy = vy + 2.5;
  }

  playerX += vx;
  playerY += vy;
}

void draw() {
  fill(fillColor);
  rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  noFill();
}
}
```

Speed power up class

```
class SpeedPWRUP {

  float diameter;
  public float pwrUpX, pwrUpY;
  int fillColor;

  void init() {
    diameter = 40;
    pwrUpX = 100;
    pwrUpY = 100;
    fillColor = color(0, 0, 255);
  }

  void update() {
    if (((playerX>pwrUpX) && (playerX < pwrUpX+diameter)) && (playerY > pwrUpY)&&(playerY>pwrUpY+diameter))
        end();
  }

  void draw() {
    fill(fillColor);
    ellipse(pwrUpX, pwrUpY, diameter, diameter);
    noFill();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do some research before posting here. Please put only relevant code snippets.

Comment: *im out of ideas.*  Here's one.  Learn the basics of the Java language by reading the Oracle Java Tutorial, or a good introductory Java textbook.

Comment: Try `thePlayer.playerX`? You would be better off with getters/setters of course.

Answer (score 2):

To check collision:
You can define a static object in your main CLASS:

```
/* global static values */
 public static Player thePlayer = new Player();
```

or list of players

```
public static ArrayList<Player> Players = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Getter functions in the Player class.
For instance:
    public float getPlayerX(){
        return playerX;
    }